# Disable "unsigned driver" warning in Windows 7 Embedded

Tags: windows, windows-7, registry, driver, windows-embedded

I am trying to automate a process in the course of which unsigned drivers have to be installed. I need to suppress the request since obviously it is not desirable to require user interaction in an automated process. The system in question is Windows 7.
I think I ran across a registry key once the changing of which accomplished exactly what I wanted *without requiring a reboot*, but my research did not turn up anything helpful this time.
As of technologies, I can utilize the command line tools that come with windows as well as .NET 4. I do not want a third party solution.

Comment: It is obviously **desirable** to have user interaction for unsigned drivers. Why else did you think Microsoft spent time and money to put that warning in? Precisely to prevent shenanigans like yours.

Comment: @MSalters On a closed system sold with specific hardware? It is indeed desirable for end users, but you would expect that Windows Embedded would allow me to control the environment that I sell.

Comment: Your original question did not mention "Window Embedded", but that is rather relevant.

Comment: @MSalters True, but there really isn't so much of a difference.